# The notification about attempt of opening newer dwg format than it can be opened

Tags: .net, autocad

AutoCAD .NET API [2009-2016]

How can I get the notification about attempt of opening newer DWG format than it can be opened in current AutoCAD?

I've searched the similar events in the *DocumentCollection Events* and *Database Events* of the *ObjectARX SDK* documentation but I found nothing...

Comment: the main point about that is the possibility of data loss (when opening newer drawings on older versions).

Comment: But you aren't confused by it when you (if necessary) through the tools of AutoCAD save DWG as older version of a format. Our long-term practice shows that the notable problems don't arise.